# I get an error when trying to start a kernel in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to connect to jupyter lab on a remote server from a local computer through a forwarded port. This workflow has previously worked for me reliably.

I have a conda environment with jupyter lab installed (. The environment has previously worked correctly, but now when I try to open a file and start a python kernel, I get a pop-up box that says:
Error Starting Kernel:
missing property: 'id'

[image]

Here is a section of the printout to the terminal. The section where it is trying to connect / start the kernel repeats until I close the jupyter server.

```
[W 2024-02-05 16:35:55.419 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.159 ServerApp] Extension package panel.io.jupyter_server_extension took 0.7394s to import
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.159 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.163 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.167 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.372 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.372 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.383 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.385 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.385 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.386 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/user/miniconda3/envs/kb/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.387 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/user/miniconda3/envs/kb/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.387 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.389 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.389 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.389 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.389 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.12.5 is running at:
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.389 ServerApp] http://localhost:8080/lab?token=xxxx
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.390 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8080/lab?token=xxxx
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.390 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-02-05 16:35:56.391 ServerApp] 
    
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-9060-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8080/lab?token=9b49283f6c14af3b1ae0300a62d954fe47954522719a5559
        http://127.0.0.1:8080/lab?token=9b49283f6c14af3b1ae0300a62d954fe47954522719a5559
[I 2024-02-05 16:35:56.773 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[W 2024-02-05 16:36:02.452 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/<path to notebook>.ipynb?content=0&1707150962323 (6e626caee75a4b0d9a49af31cb44bcc9@127.0.0.1) 1.35ms referer=http://localhost:8080/lab
[W 2024-02-05 16:36:02.452 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/<path to notebook>.ipynb?content=0&1707150962323 (127.0.0.1): No such file or directory: <path to notebook>.ipynb
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:02.659 LabApp] Build is up to date
[W 2024-02-05 16:36:17.585 ServerApp] Notebook <path to notebook>.ipynb is not trusted
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.109 ServerApp] Kernel started: 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.525 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e.
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.589 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e:fd107c37-67af-4579-becf-c4f6d6bb7918
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.618 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e.
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.681 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e:f792b2c3-8cfd-4921-9a63-1f2d2711fbaf
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.716 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e.
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.780 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e:fd107c37-67af-4579-becf-c4f6d6bb7918
[I 2024-02-05 16:36:18.853 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 2bde3e7d-2579-483e-a9b7-f92f4ed6e26e.
```

The issue also happens on python 3.10.

If I connect to jupyter lab on a different local computer, the issue isn't present. Previously I cleared my browser cache, and that seemed to fix the problem for a day, but now I have the error again and clearing the cache doesn't seem to work.

I have tried restarting my machine, restarting jupyter, uninstalling / reinstalling jupyter, and creating a new conda environment from scratch, and deleting existing workspaces (.jupyter/lab/workspaces).